# Should The WhatsApp Tag Be Removed?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me there are more and more questions using the `whatsapp` tag. The questions are almost always addressing some issue with or question about the app. And almost all of them are questions that really ought to be sent to WhatsApp support. (See [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/contacts-not-seen), [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8902/bugs-in-lumia-730-with-whatsapp), [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8889/nokia-lumia-730-whatsapp), and [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8882/can-i-transfer-all-my-whatsapp-info-from-android-to-windows-phone), to list a few.) The problem is that WhatsApp isn't really even part of the Windows Phone system; it's an app. And so if people can ask questions about WhatsApp here, why not questions about every other app on the Store? Should the `whatsapp` tag be removed to discourage these questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, this is a good question - and a tough one! I'm not really sure yet where I land on this one. But for the moment I would say we keep because

- WhatsApp is one of the most popular apps and answering a question for one user potentially helps many people
- WhatsApp does not seem to provide an open support platform
- The Android Stackexchange site has a `whatsapp` tag as well

I would say we keep an eye on how the quality of answers to WhatsApp questions develops and make a decision based on that. Of course this will open up a new discussion on what apps are big enough to get their own tags / what questions are allowed.

Comment: And Whatsapp port to Windows Phone is pretty bad. I think in this case we can let them pass. Because a lot of things are indeed O.S. related.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Thomas said, in my opinion removing the tag will accomplish nothing. People will simply use some other tag and post the question regardless.

Further, I'm not sure we would want to discourage people from posting support-type questions here. On the contrary, we want this site to be the first stop for people with questions about Windows Phone or any apps that run on it. If the occasional question really is of the technical sort better addressed to an official support channel, we can tell them so, but they'll still remember this site as being helpful. Plus the small overhead is, I believe, far outweighed by the possibility of getting good questions with actual solutions that might help many other people as well.

As for questions about any other app in the Store, I say as long as they don't run foul of our [what to ask](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) / [what not to ask](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) guidelines, bring them on :)